# How not to show the path when virtualenv is activated

Tags: python, windows, cmd, virtualenv

So, when a python virtualenv is activated on Windows, the console line prompts something as:

```
(env_name) C:\env_path>
```

Sometimes however the path can get too big, so hiding it and leaving the console something like this would be really helpful:

```
(env_name) >
```

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `prompt ^>`  in cmd. Make sure you include the space after the angled bracket (`>`).

If you wish to do it permanently, you can add that line at the end of your `activate.bat` script.